# Rollback commit in .GIT

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I've just pulled on the live server some changes that I don't want on there yet. I need to rollback to the previous version before the last pull.

But i'm not sure of the correct command or how to get the hash for the previous commit that I want to rollback to. Any help much appreciated.

I managed to rollback the head with the following command

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Which put my head back to the right point.

But it still appears to have pulled down the changes on the server and I need to now remove the files.

I also have just tried

```
git clean -f
```

Which I thought from reading would remove the unwanted added code and files. Seems to have removed the files, but not the code in existing files.

Comment: Could you please enhance your question by providing the following additional information? How do you "pull" on the server (is Git deployed there)? Where (on your development computer? on the server?)  did you run the "git reset" and "git clean" commands?

Comment: Did your pull include --rebase?  (ie, does your log show a merge commit)?  Try looking in your reflog and reset --hard to the last commit before the pull.

Comment: Nope just a straight forward git pull.

Comment: I've kinda of fixed it now, but using git revert and the hash to roll back to,

Comment: However, I could really do with bringing it forward a commit now, what's the best way to do that?

Comment: Why is the SVN tag here?

Answer (score 1):

`git reset --hard` should have resynced your workspace to previous commit you rolled back to, so what do you mean by "I need to now remove the files", exactly? Yes, git will have the new change from the remote server tracked in origin/master, but that shouldn't be a problem. Is `git diff` or `git status` showing differences? If so, `git reset HEAD -- .`, `git checkout -- .` will revert everything.

Comment: Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.

Comment: This is what it says when doing a git checkout, however the files within the repository are still up to date.

Comment: What I need to know the answer for really is how to now rollback the files to the write versions of them. The head seems to be doing something.

Comment: "Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit" - this is just re-iterating that there is one commit on the remote server ('origin/master' is the local copy that tracks that) that you don't have in your local workspace, i.e. the situation you seem to want. So if there are no other changes described by `git status` you should be in the right situation, how aren't you *exactly*?

Comment: I had to use git revert #hash to actually bring the files up to date not just the git head.

Comment: Is it possible to git pull #hash or how can I now bring the repo forward to a specific commit in the future as the most recent commit must be avoided.

Comment: `git reset --hard commit_hash`